# SQL Select sum from one column

Tags: mysql

I have a table with txntype and amount:

```
Table A
Rec   txntype    amount
 1    6          500
 2    7          400
 3    6          500
 4    7          600
```

I need to create a query where I can get the sum of amount based on txn type:

```
Output Query
Rec    AmountA    AmountB
1      1000       1000
```

Where AmountA is txntype = 6 and AmountB is txntype = 7.  Can a sql select statement can be use like this:

```
select amount as a, amount as b CASE amount
WHEN
txntype    = 6 THEN SUM(amount) to a
WHEN 
txntype    = 7 THEN SUM(amount) to b
END
from Table 
group by amount;
```

I'm new to sql and sorry if the query has a bunch of errors but not sure if it can be done using query or need to use stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do a conditional aggregation of the `amount` column, depending on the value of `txntype`.

```
SELECT Rec,
       SUM(CASE WHEN txntype = 6 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS AmountA,
       SUM(CASE WHEN txntype = 7 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS AmountB
FROM PayrollTxn
```

Note that you don't need to use `GROUP BY` in this case, because the `CASE` expression in the `SUM()` functions above take care of aggregating the amounts for `txttype` value.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 0):

Try this should solve your problem :

```
SELECT 1 AS Rec,
SUM(A.Amount) as AmmountA, 
(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM PayrollTxn WHERE txntype=7) as AmmountB
FROM PayrollTxn AS A
WHERE txntype = 6
GROUP BY A.Amount
```

See here demo : [MySql select sum query](http://rextester.com/WWBJ51445)